# Phonegap iOS application got rejected for GPS usage

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation, location, appstore-approval

> 2.16 Thank you for adding the disclaimer(about battery usage), however we noticed your app is using geo-fencing features. This is not an
>   appropriate use of the location background mode.
>
> Please consider location region monitoring or the significant change location service,
>   both of which do not require the "location" string in the
>   UIBackgroundModes key of the info.plist. 
>   Best Regards, App Review

The problem is we removed `UIBackgroundModes` "location" string completely, so geo-updates with `getLocation()` method are perfomed only in app foreground mode.

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resubmitted once again, not really fixing anything major and got approved. Guess revision group haven't noticed "location" string was removed from .plist in previous release.